# Double conditional jQuery function event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How do I specify a second condition that requires that the user not only click a link but click in the area between a div in order to go to landing.html?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script> 

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#postos").click(function() { 
            $("#linkos").attr('href', 'landing.html');
        });

        $('#clickdiv div').click(function () { 
            $("#linkos").attr('href', 'landing.html');
        });

    });


</script>

<a id="postos" href="#"></a>

<div id="clickdiv">please click</div>

<a id="linkos" href='javascript:window.alert("click the link and div");'><br/><img src="pic.png"></a>
```

Comment: You can't do that; it makes no sense.

Comment: What do you mean with "between a div"? Your `#clickdiv div` selector doesn't select anything by the way.

Comment: `$('#clickdiv div')` is looking for a div element inside your div with id `#clickdiv`

Comment: Why would go to the trouble to even type div with clickdiv?

Comment: the div would contain stuff like  pictures, iframes etc. I think it would be easier to attach an event to a div rather than each item in the div.

Comment: What about binding the event to the div? It will also fire if you click descendants (elements the div contains).

Comment: i tried<p> tags ...still not working http://jsfiddle.net/4fdYH/

Answer (score 0):

I ***STRONGLY*** suggest you go about this differently. Using divs in this manner SCREAMS poor design; not to mention, forcing users to click multiple elements feels clunky and tedious.

However, I have provided you an example of how to do so: http://jsfiddle.net/2q3SQ/27/.

I have also provided you with another example that might be more useful:
http://jsfiddle.net/2q3SQ/28/

Links (MAY BE USEFUL):

- http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/