# Two-step process with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is the flow:

The user is required to click a link to google.com and then click the text between `<p>` tags (in no particular order, but both actions must occur).

If he does the above, when he clicks on the pic.png he will go to yahoo.com.

Otherwise, he gets an alert.

So far here is my attempt

http://jsfiddle.net/p8epF/

Comment: Your fiddle is broken because you can only add javascript in the JS window. Pick jQuery in the sidebar, then put your HTML in the top box and the contents of your <script> tags in the bottom-left box.

Comment: Does the link to google.com open in a new window or something?

Comment: You [just asked this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168319/double-conditional-jquery-function-event) less than an hour ago...

Comment: Like @MrOBrian pointed out you already asked this question recently. Please don't spam the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="postos" href="http://google.com">eeee</a>
<p id="click">please click</p>
<a id="linkos"><img src="pic.png"></a>​
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    var clicked = false;

    $("#linkos").on("click", function(){
        if (clicked) {
           window.location = 'http://google.com';
        } else {
           alert("Not clicked!");
        }        
    });


    $("#click").on("click", function(){
        clicked = true;     
    });

})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ef7ZT/

Answer (score 0):

What you need can be done easily with [jquery promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/): http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/WXVPf/1/

```
var yahoo = $('#yahoo'),
    googleClicked = $.Deferred(),
    textClicked = $.Deferred();

yahoo.on('click', function() {
    alert('you need to click google and some text');
});

$('#google').on('click', function() {
    googleClicked.resolve();
});

$('p').on('click', function() {
    textClicked.resolve();
});

$.when(googleClicked, textClicked).done(function() {
    yahoo.off('click')
         .on('click', function() {
             alert('you have finished this strange quest successfully');
         });
});

​
```

For the ones who don't use `$.Deferred` yet - there is an amazing article: http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Comment: can you add some explanation please... like what happens after we click on google, what do resolve() do

Comment: I think the link to the docs offers a pretty good explanation. This is a fairly simple way of using Deferred objects; quite easy to follow the code if you understand them (which the docs help you to do).

Comment: @sabithpocker: isn't that what documentation for?

Comment: @zerkms Laziness easily gets caught in SO :)

Comment: @sabithpocker: actually I've given a link with perfect explanation. PS: I cannot agree that writing almost ready to use solution is called "laziness" ;-)

Comment: @zerkms I mentioned about my laziness to go and read the docs :) Im reading the link now, thank you for that.